# Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: methods, static, scope, instance

I'm trying to call a method from another class and from what I've gathered, the method I'm trying to call is an instance method.  I've gathered that, that means it uses instance variables of an object.  Is there an easy way to call this method?

This is the main method,

```
public void main()
{
    Test.testPetOwner();
}
```

And this is the method I'm trying to call in a class called "Test"

```
public void testPetOwner()
{
    String petName;
    String species;
    String hairCondition;
    String posture;

    testCompetitor();

    PetOwner petOwner1 = new PetOwner();

    System.out.println("What is the pet's name?");
    petName = Genio.getString();
    petOwner1.setPetName(petName);

    System.out.println("What is the species of the pet?");
    species = Genio.getString();
    petOwner1.setSpecies(species);

    System.out.println("What is the hair condition of the pet?");
    hairCondition = Genio.getString();
    petOwner1.setHairCondition(hairCondition);

    System.out.println("How is the pet's posture?");
    posture = Genio.getString();
    petOwner1.setPosture(posture);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void main()
{
    Test t = new Test();
    t.testPetOwner();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  It always seems obvious when you see the answer!

Answer (score 0):

If we try to access an instance method from a static context , compiler has now way to guess which instance method ( variable for which object ), you are referring too. Though you can always access it using object reference.